# Pandas, append column based on unique subset of column values

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, dataframe

I have a dataframe with many rows.  I am appending a column using data produced from a custom function, like this:

```
import numpy

df['new_column'] = numpy.vectorize(fx)(df['col_a'], df['col_b'])
# takes 180964.377 ms
```

It is working fine, what I am trying to do is speed it up.  There is really only a small group of unique combinations of `col_a` and `col_b`.  Many of the iterations are redundant.  I was thinking maybe `pandas` would just figure that out on its own but I don't think that is the case.  Consider this:

```
print len(df.index) #prints 127255
df_unique = df.copy().drop_duplicates(['col_a', 'col_b'])
print len(df_unique.index) #prints 9834
```

I also convinced myself of the possible speedup by running this:

```
df_unique['new_column'] = numpy.vectorize(fx)(df_unique['col_a'], df_unique['col_b'])
# takes 14611.357 ms
```

Since there is a lot of redundant data, what I am trying to do is update the large dataframe ( `df` 127255 rows ) but only need to run the `fx` function the minimum amount of times ( 9834 times ).  This is because of all the duplicate rows for `col_a` and `col_b`.  Of course this means that there will be multiple rows in `df` that have the same values for `col_a` and `col_b`, but that is OK, the other columns of `df` are different and make each row unique.

Before I create a normal iterative for loop to loop through the `df_unique` dataframe and do a conditional update on `df`, I wanted to ask if there was a more "pythonic" neat way of doing this kind of update.  Thanks a lot.

** UPDATE **

I created the simple for loop mentioned above, like this:

```
df = ...
df_unique = df.copy().drop_duplicates(['col_a', 'col_b'])
df_unique['new_column'] = np.vectorize(fx)(df_unique['col_a'], df_unique['col_b'])
for index, row in df_unique.iterrows():         
    df.loc[(df['col_a'] == row['col_a']) & (df['col_b'] == row['col_b']),'new_column'] = row['new_column']
# takes 165971.890
```

So with this for loop there may be a slight performance increase but not nearly what I would have expected.

**FYI**

This is the `fx` function.  It queries a mysql database.

```
def fx(d):
    exp_date = datetime.strptime(d.col_a, '%m/%d/%Y')
    if exp_date.weekday() == 5:
        exp_date -= timedelta(days=1)

    p = pandas.read_sql("select stat from table where a = '%s' and b_date = '%s';" % (d.col_a,exp_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')),engine)
    if len(p.index) == 0:
        return None
    else:
        return p.iloc[0].close
```

Comment: What kind of data is in `col_a`, `col_b`? Are they already sorted?

Comment: They are both strings, although col_b is a date string.  Fairly certain they are sorted.  They appear to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

if you can manage to read up your three columns `['stat','a','b_date']` belonging to `table` table into `tab` DF then you could merge it like this:

```
tab = pd.read_sql('select stat,a,b_date from table', engine)
df.merge(tab, left_on=[...], right_on=[...], how='left')
```

**OLD answer:**

you can merge/join your precalculated `df_unique` DF with the original `df` DF:

```
df['new_column'] = df.merge(df_unique, on=['col_a','col_b'], how='left')['new_column']
```

Comment: Very nice and fast, thank you.  i measured 14960 ms, compared to about the same just for updating the `df_unique` DF so that is more what I was expecting to be possible.

Comment: I just haven't had a time to go through everything, but this answer is the simplest and the speed is really good.  I also think replacing numpy.vectorize with dataframe.apply, from the other answer also improved the speed slightly.

Comment: I posted the `fx` function.  If you can see any improvements that would be wonderful.

Answer (score 1):

MaxU's answer may be already something you want. But I'll show another approach which may be a bit faster (I didn't measure).

I assume that:

1. `df[['col_a', 'col_b']]` is sorted so that all identical entries are in consecutive rows (it's important)
2. `df` has a unique index (if not, you may create some temporary unique index).

I'll use the fact that `df_unique.index` is a subset of `df.index`.

```
# (keep='first' is actually default)
df_unique = df[['col_a', 'col_b']].drop_duplicates(keep='first').copy()

# You may try .apply instead of np.vectorize (I think it may be faster):
df_unique['result'] = df_unique.apply(fx, axis=1)

# Main part:
df['result'] = df_unique['result']                     # uses 2.
df['result'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)      # uses 1.
```

Comment: +1 for the `apply` function.  I had seen this but didn't realize it would take the whole row as argument.  I think the ffill method isn't working perfectly for me.  I guess I didn't mention that the function returns `None` sometimes, so there are some rows that need to remain NaN, but i think the ffill is filling them all in.  Anyways thanks for the help.

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind Oh, I see. A workaround would be to fill `None`s in `df_unique` with some neutral value (say, -1), then assign to `df`, `fillna`, and change -1 back to None/np.nan. But, apart from this, the whole solution is rather a hack. If you don't need more speedup, using `merge` is just safer.