# Combine rows of a single file based on multiple matched columns, while retaining unique content by appending additional columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm sure this code exists and I've read through a LOT of pandas / python documentation, in fact perhaps my answer is contained within [Pandas, append column based on unique subset of column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37527401/pandas-append-column-based-on-unique-subset-of-column-values) but we can't seem to get it to work as below.

Using the example below, if both the Company and Place match, we want to combine the rest of the columns. IF there is unique data, then we would to retain the data in that column and append it as an additional column.

Here is the visual representation of what we need:

[image]

Comment: As you've read a lot of SO questions then you must know that questions with images are rarely received well can you produce a [mcve] and you'll get a response quite quickly.

Comment: What do you currently have instead?

Comment: Thanks, I currently use a simple script that we use to merge two files 
df2 = df1.merge(df, on='Company', how='right')
But I didn't know how to get the same result on a single file